# Casting PropertyInfo.PropertyType to enum

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I have a generic function to create objects from a `DataRow` using reflection. I'm using this function to import tables from an Access database:

```
private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
{
    T item = new T();
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        try
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                prop.SetValue(item, row[prop.Name], null); // what to do??
            else
                prop.SetValue(item, row[prop.Name], null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, string.Format("failed to assign {0} a value of {1}", prop.Name, row[prop.Name]));
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is when the property type is an `enum`. I've tried using `Enum.Parse`, but that hasn't been successful (I can't get anything to compile).

Is there any way to convert the object represented by `row[prop.Name]` to the correct `enum` using my function? Or do I need to write a special conversion function specific for the `enum`s I've defined.

**Edit**: 
I am getting

> "the type or namespace prop could not be found. Are you missing an assembly directive or reference" 
>   compile error for the following:

`var val = (prop.PropertyType)Enum.Parse(typeof(prop.PropertyType), row[prop.Name].ToString());`

Comment: can you please specify encountered errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the `type or namespace prop could not be found` exception you were getting is because you cannot cast to a type in this way `(prop.PropertyType)Enum.Parse(typeof(prop.PropertyType)` - you can only do that where you know the type at compile time - `(SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum)`.

The correct way to do it is to get the enum value before setting the property value:

```
prop.SetValue(item, Enum.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, row[prop.Name]), null);
```

Comment: I used your solution but i got this error

System.ArgumentException: 'The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.
Parameter name: value'

Answer (score 0):

My class is like this

```
public enum Status
{
    Active,
    Deactive
}

public class Sample
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Status UserStatus{ get; set; }
}
```

In database i stored Status="Active" as string.
I used your solution, but got following error

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32. Parameter name: value'
```